# Windows 8 standard VCL style/theme

Tags: windows-8, c++builder, vcl, vcl-styles, c++builder-xe5

I'm currently using Rad Studio XE5, and I want to create my own style based on the standard Windows 8 style (not modern UI). I'm using the built-in designer in Rad Studio called Bitmap Style Designer. However, I can't seem to fint a vsf-file for the Windows theme. Does anybody know where I can find this, or if it exists? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a vsf.  I'm also looking for this but have been unable to find one.

Comment: @themaniac27 I build it up from scratch. But I also made some changes so it matches our company style and color.